# How to use homebrew to downgrade postgresql from 10.1 to 9.6 on Mac OS

Tags: macos, postgresql, downgrade

My mac has postgresql 10.1 on it, and I need 9.6 for my work website to function on my local machine.  Can't find easy instructions on how to uninstall or downgrade to 9.6. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: how did you get 10.1 on it in the first place? via `brew`, or another installer?

Comment: I used brew install method

Comment: * `brew uninstall postgresql` should allow you to remove the currently installed version
* `brew search postgresql` will show you the available versions
* `brew install postgresql@9.6` will install

if you find yourself switching frequently between postgres versions - you may want to look into using `docker` for handling these

Comment: You are the man

Answer (score 123):

I got this issue as well after running `brew upgrade`. Following commands worked for me:

```
brew uninstall postgresql
brew install postgresql@9.6
brew services start postgresql@9.6
brew link postgresql@9.6 --force
```

Comment: For those of us using the PostgresApp, click on the elephant icon in the top status bar, click 'Open Postgres', click the icon on the bottom of the Postgres window to open the side panel, click the '+' icon. Now you'll be given a menu where you can select the version you want your Postgres server to run.

Comment: Another way is switching to version 9.6 without uninstalling postgresql `brew switch postgres 9.6.3`, then restart postgresql `brew services restart postgresql`

Comment: Another way is to simply upgrade your data directory.  Run this command.  Tested for going from 13 to 14:
`brew postgresql-upgrade-database`