# Homebrew downgrade Python 3.7.x to 3.7.3

Tags: python, homebrew, python-3.7

Is it possible using homebrew to downgrade latest version of python (currently 3.7.5) to 3.7.3?

Comment: more or less the same steps described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47294258/how-to-use-homebrew-to-downgrade-postgresql-from-10-1-to-9-6-on-mac-os

Comment: `brew install python@3.7.3` for python returns error **No available formulae**.  From the brew docs, I am cannot see how that can be used for python

Comment: They may not maintain older versions for that tap - not all projects do. If a simple `@3.7.3` isn't available there's still ways to get older versions but it is a bit painful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46306176/1431244